# Responsive Web Design Flaw

Tags: positioning, media-queries

I am trying to make this site more responsive and have started by making all the attributes in responsive terms such as % and ems, but for some reason it isn't as responsive as I would like. I decided to use media queries to make up for the design flaws.

I've been reading Responsive Web Design by Ethan Marcotte and it helps a lot with most of the design, but the media queries don't seem to be working for my iPad or iPod (aka I'm doing something wrong).

Can anyone readily identify what it is that I'm doing wrong?

http://thelglymovement.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see your code to be completely sure, but from what I can see when I pull up your website, the stylesheet imports below are not actually finding the files from your project folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/skeleton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css"/>
```

the only file that seems to be loaded is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" />
```

and it does not include any media queries.

When I resize the website in Google Chrome I am not seeing any responsive changes which makes sense because 3 of your style sheets aren't present.

Comment: You also have a static width of 1200px on your #main div that wraps everything which keeps any of the children elements fluid percentage widths from doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If it seems to be working in your desktop browsers, but the media queries aren't working on mobile I would might take a guess you don't have the viewport meta tag. i.e.  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This makes sure that the mobile devices don't try to scale your webpage down to fit their device size, instead allowing you to determine widths in your CSS (and media queries). This [MDN article on the viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) might be useful for more info.